# Какой корень в слове "поет" - "по" или "п"?

Tags: морфемный-разбор, морфология

Answer (score 5):

" Чтобы выделить основу
настоящего / простого будущего
времени, нужно отделить от формы
настоящего/простого будущего
времени личное окончание;
предпочтительнее использовать
форму 3 лица множественного числа
(так как сама эта основа в разных
формах может иметь разный вид):
пиш-ут, работаj-ут, леч-ат." [Ссылка](http://rusolimp.kopeisk.ru/morfemika/?file=115)

Поет, поют : поj-ут. Корень поj, пой.

Для справки : " У глагола выделяются две основы :
основа инфинитива и основа
настоящего/простого будущего
времени. (Иногда выделяется ещё и
основа прошедшего времени, но у
большинства глаголов она совпадает с
основой инфинитива.) Часть
глагольных форм образуется от основы
инфинитива, а другая часть - от
основы настоящего/простого будущего
времени. Эти две основы у многих
глаголов различаются." [Ссылка](http://rusolimp.kopeisk.ru/morfologia/?file=108)

Пример:

Пе-ть, пе-л, пе-вший, с-пе-в

Поj-ут, пой, поj-ущий

Comment: Если бы в русском языке не было нелепой буквы "ё", введенной в обращение кн.  Дашковой, тогда бы предложение "Она поёт." записывалось в виде "Она пойот.", а фамилии "Царёв" и "Рублёв" записывалась в виде "Царьов" и "Рубльов".

P.S. Глупость "советского человека" проявлялась в том, что он выпускал в обращение монеты номиналом "15 копеек".

Answer (score 4):

ПОЁТ. Графический корень --- ПО-, графическое окончание --- -ЁТ. Более точный морфемный анализ --- фонетический: /П∆J-О΄Т/  (значок ∆ передает реализацию фонемы <O> в первом предударном слоге).
 В современном русском языке в данном корне наблюдается историческое чередование звуков
 /Э/ //  /ОJ/ :  ПЕ-ть --- ПО-ЁТ. Оно связано с судьбой доисторического дифтонга */Оİ/ в положении закрытого слога в связи с законом открытого слога: перед согласным он монофтонгизировался в звук* /ę/ ("ять"), который уже в русском языке совпал со звуком /Э/, отсюда в современном русском языке ПЕ-ть.İ А перед гласным дифтонг распался на два слога, испытав при этом изменение неслогового звука /İ/  в согласный /J/: */Oİ/ -->* /OJ/, отсюда в русском языке ПО/J-о/т.

Comment: Так каков ответ-то? 
Насчет дифтонга - это да, не возражаю. 
Интересно только, Вы кого-то цитируете или это Ваши копирайты?

Comment: Валентина, просьба к Вам! Фонетически представьте такой вот ряд : пьют, пей, пьющий. С комментарием, если можно...

Comment: ПЬЮТ --- /ПJ-ут/,
ПЕЙ --- /ПЭЙ- 0- 0/ (повелительное наклонение выражается нулевым суффиксом, а грамматические значения 2л ед.числа --- нулевым окончанием), 
ПЬЮЩИЙ --- /ПJ- уш - ий/ (буква Ш в данном случае передает долгий мягкий звук /Ш/).
 Таким образом, в современном корне наблюдаются чередования звуков: /0гласного звука/ // /э/,  /j/  //  /й/ (эти звуки --- реализация фонемы <J> в разных позициях).

Comment: Уважаемый begemotus, ответ дан (см. выше). Не цитирую --- это мой ответ. Мне посчастливилось читать историко-лингвистические курсы на филологических факультетах в течение 45 лет.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Наконец-то профессиональный лингвист в наших рядах.

Comment: Спасибо за добрые слова!

Answer (score 2):

А что тогда является окончанием, если ЁТ - суффикс?

Comment: по-ет, по-ют - конечно, это окончания. Личные глагольные окончания.

Comment: По современным представлениям "окончания" глаголов являются формообразующими суффиксами. Ранее их действительно относили к флексиям, возможно в школе это практикуется до сих пор. Вопрос не совсем терминологический, за ним стоит кое-что достаточно серьезное в описании грамматики языка, только поэтому я и сообщаю об этом.  
Но для данной темы это вопрос не слишком принципиальный. Главное, что это никак не корень.
[Л.С.СТЕПАНОВА, Cуффикс или Окончание ][1]     
[1]: http://irgali.narod.ru/files/suffiks_ili_okonshanie.htm

Comment: Думаю, что это не отражает точки зрения большинства лингвистов.Иначе этими же терминами оперировали бы и академические справочники. А они ведь не только для школяров. Тот же Лопатин пишет о правописании глагольных окончаний, а не суффиксов.

Comment: Прочитала статью по ссылке. Боже, да вы внимательно прочитайте! Там ведь ни слова не говорится о личных окончаниях - суффиксах. Там вообще ничего революционного нет. Все это и так принято в школьной грамматике. Но не все авторы учебников строго классифицируют формообразующие и словообразующие суффиксы. Автор статьи призывает сделать это последовательно. Вот и все. Речь у Степановой идет о суффиксах инфинитива, прошедшего времени. причастий и деепричастий. Ноги растут из разного понимания причастия и деепричастия: часть речи или форма глагола?

Answer (score 0):

Корень - "По". "-ёт" - личный глагольный суффикс.
Сложности связаны с тем, что данный корень (как и вообще многие древние) в современном языке потерял фонетическое единство. В "петь" этот же корень выступает в форме "пе", причем "е" в нем является сращением двух морфов: оно принадлежит одновременно и корню, и суффиксу. Хотя это уже вопрос систематики, в школе до такого обычно не доходят.

Comment: Опять начинаются фиги в кармане...  
Уважаемая, определить Вас не составляет труда, но дело не в этом.
Неужели совершенно искреннему "спасибо" за содержательную критику вы предпочитаете репутацию тайной пакостницы?  
Или Вы тоже - очередной минусящий мульт?!

Comment: А разве надо объяснять очевидное. Плюсы у Инны - объяснение вашего минуса